# Как настроить удаленное подключение к mysql?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Не получается подключиться удаленно к mysql серверу.

В ubuntu-сервере в конфигах mysql я настроил, чтобы он был доступен с любого адреса:

```
> netstat -nap | grep mysql
tcp6  0    0 :::3306   :::*       LISTEN        80185/mysqld
unix  2    [ ACC ]    STREAM     LISTENING     2499807  80185/mysqld      /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3    [ ]        STREAM     CONNECTED     2678908  109866/mysql
unix  3    [ ]        STREAM     CONNECTED     2678296  80185/mysqld      /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3    [ ]        STREAM     CONNECTED     2677308  80185/mysqld      /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3    [ ]        STREAM     CONNECTED     2674988  109818/mysql
```

Создал пользователя в mysql с доступом из любого хоста:

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> select user, host from user where user='testdbuser';
+------------+----------------+
| user       | host           |
+------------+----------------+
| testdbuser | %              |
+------------+----------------+
```

И после этого когда пытаюсь подключиться к БД со своего ПК Workbench мне выдает :

> Failed to connect to mysql at with user testdbuser. Access denied for user 'testdbuser'@'94.230.162.107' (using password:YES)

Когда проверяю подключение по telnet, то он мне выдает:

> Got packets out of orderConnection closed by foreign host.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так???

Comment: Обычно подобное (если не считать косины в пароле) наблюдают, когда пользователю не выданы права на подключение к БД, указанной как дефолтная. Или права выданы, а привилегии не сброшены.

Comment: выполните flush privileges; в консоли mysql